# Who read/write my application's memory

Tags: windows

Each Application has its memory space. In Windows, all process can use "OpenProcess" and "ReadProcessMemory/WriteProcessMemory(NtReadVirtualMemory/NtWriteVirtualMemory)" to read or write memory of application.

In System kernel, we can hook SSDT function "NtReadVirtualMemory/NtWriteVirtualMemory" to check who read and write memory of Application.

I have a question: Is there a way to check who read and write memory of Application in this application's process?

Comment: no. not without hooking other processes/kernel (by hooking SSDT, as you've mentioned in your question). You can check which process has a handle to your application, but that doesn't necessarily mean that they've actually read/written anything.

Comment: Thank you, JosephH. How can I check which process has a handle to my application?  Is there any document about it?

Comment: I don't believe you are going to be able to hook the SSDT in modern versions of Windows. [Kernel Patch Protection (i.e., Patch Guard)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_Patch_Protection) should prohibit. You *may* be able to use the Kernel Data and Filtering Support API.

Answer (score 4):

No. Not without hooking other processes/kernel (by hooking SSDT, as you've mentioned in your question). You can check which process has a handle to your application, but that doesn't necessarily mean that they've actually read/written anything.

To see which process has a handle to your process,

1. Call [`NtQuerySystemInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with [`SystemHandleInformation`](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/System%20Information/SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS.html#SystemHandleInformation)(undocumented) for `SystemInformationClass` parameter, to enumerate all handles that are open on the system.
2. Duplicate all handles by calling [`DuplicateHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` access (if I recall correctly, this will filter out all non-process handles)
3. For each duplicated handle, call [`GetProcessId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the process-id.
4. If the process-id matches with your application's process-id, then we can get the owner of the original handle by looking up the `ProcessId` field of the original `SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION` structure returned from `NtQuerySystemInformation`.

Comment: JosephH, I have other question: Some process "OpenProcess" and injects code to my application. After it injects, it free the handle. So, your way may be miss it. how can I fix it?

Comment: @wenz then you'll have to hook `NtOpenProcess` as soon as possible. There's only so much you can do when you're in the user mode... By the way, if the injection involves `CreateRemoteThread`, it is possible to intercept the creation of the new thread by hooking `RtlUserThreadStart`. But again, this might be useless if the process doing the injection creates the thread using `NtCreateThread `with custom `CONTEXT` structure.

Comment: In win7 32bit, I hook "NtOpenProcess". because of the PATCH GUARD in 64bit, I can not hook "NtOpenProcess" in kernel. So I have to find other way. I think if I know who read and write memory of application, I can protect my application.

Comment: @wenz The bottom line: If you're trying to do this to protect your application, then my advice to you is: don't bother. As long as your application lies in the memory, there's simply no foolproof way of protecting it.